# neo4j neosemantics: loading model constraints

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neosemantics

I want to use neosemantics to validate a graph in neo4j, but I'm having trouble to get the model constraints loaded on a minimal example:

Suppose I have the following graph:

```
CREATE (n:Person {name: 'Andy'})
```

Then, I initialize neosemantics as follows:

```
CALL n10s.graphconfig.init();
```

Now I should be good to go and validate the graph. Based on what I found here (https://neo4j.com/labs/neosemantics/4.0/validation/),
I thought that the following schema should work as a first approach:

```
call n10s.validation.shacl.import.inline('

@prefix neo4j: <http://neo4j.com/myvoc#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .

neo4j:PersonShape a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetClass neo4j:Person ;
  sh:property [
    sh:path neo4j:name ;
    sh:datatype xsd:string ;
  ];
.','Turtle')
```

However, that gives me:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `n10s.validation.shacl.import.inline`: Caused by: n10s.utils.UriUtils$UriNamespaceHasNoAssociatedPrefix: Prefix Undefined: No prefix defined for namespace <http://neo4j.com/myvoc#Person>. Use n10s.nsprefixes.add(...) procedure.
```

It felt weird, but to match that error message, I tried adding the line

```
@prefix neo4jPerson: <http://neo4j.com/myvoc#Person> .
```

but that didn't help.

I then tried the following:

```
CALL n10s.graphconfig.init({handleVocabUris:"IGNORE"});
```

Then, the validation rule is accepted, but it doesn't really look connected to anything:

```
target  propertyOrRelationshipPath  param   value
"__NONE__"  "__NONE__"  "datatype"  "string"
```

I thought that it would be helpful to remove that namespace stuff all along. So I also tried

```
call n10s.validation.shacl.import.inline('

@prefix neo4j: <http://neo4j.com/myvoc#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .

PersonShape a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetClass Person ;
  sh:property [
    sh:path name ;
    sh:datatype xsd:string ;
  ];
.','Turtle')
```

But that didn't work either as the parser insists on getting that namespace stuff to work:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `n10s.validation.shacl.import.inline`: Caused by: org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.RDFParseException: Expected ':', found ' ' [line 6]
```

I'm a bit at a loss here. The code I've given is more or less taken from the neosemantics user guide (https://neo4j.com/labs/neosemantics/4.0/).
and only adapted slightly. Their unit tests also seem to have no magic added https://github.com/neo4j-labs/neosemantics/blob/4.0/src/test/java/n10s/validation/SHACLValidationProceduresTest.java#L59. Still I'm getting the error messages outlined above. What am I missing? Is there a MWE of anyone that got neo4j graph validation to work?

Comment: perhaps this post might help: https://grant592.github.io/prog-neo4j/

Comment: @TomažBratanič thank you, but the link does not deal with validation. I did some more digging and I think there might be a bug in neosemantics. I'll keep this post updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, the neo4j namespace has changed to `<neo4j://graph.schema#>` (https://github.com/neo4j-labs/neosemantics/issues/229)